# Answer Order Bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, voting

I have noticed a bug [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do) on answers for a question. The answers aren't displaying in order of votes, like they should be.

Here is a screenshot to demonstrate:

[image]

I have refreshed the page, reopened the browser and even restarted my computer.

I am using Windows 8.1 with the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: Are you sure you're not ordering it based on "active"? what you're displaying looks like the "Active" ordering to me

Comment: You can find the [filteroptions](http://i.imgur.com/jo0dZ0R.png) under the question.

Comment: It seems I am. Didn't realize I had them sorted as active. Thankyou @Wipqozn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're filtering by **active**, not by votes.

[image: filtering by active]

Active is the default behaviour, as it shows the answers which are more likely to be up to date, as 'active' takes into account edit dates as well as when the answer was posted.

To view the answers in order of votes instead, click the 'votes' link.